# jQuery - How to scroll an anchor to the top of the page when clicked?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a list of links in `div` elements and I am using dropcontent.js to load content into another `div` when a link is clicked. I would now like to add some code which scrolls the clicked link to the top of the browser window.

HTML is like this for each item in the list:

```
<div class="work">
    <h3><a class="scroll" href="project2.html">Project 2</a></h3>
    <div class="projectIntro">
        <p>This is some intro text for project 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pictures"></div>
</div>
```

I have found tutorials for scrolling to an ID when a link is clicked (by making the href the ID of the div you want to scroll to - unfortunately I can't do this as my href is actually a separate html page even though it is using dropcontent to load it into the current page.

I also found a tutorial for scrolling to a particular ID on page load, but none that simply say when an anchor of a given class is clicked, scroll it to the top of the browser window.

Can someone help me out with this one please? thanks.

UPDATE:

I have got the scroll working using the following code:

```
$('.work a').click(function() {
         $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top}, 500);
         });
```

However, my dropcontent.js is no longer working... I think because I have 2 functions occuring on the same click... I would like the content to load first, then scroll.

here is my dropcontent.js

```
$('.work a').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

var parent = $(this).parents(".work");
var content_holder = parent.children(".pictures");

if (parent.hasClass("selected_work")) {
  close_other();
  return;
}

close_other();

parent.addClass("selected_work");
content_holder.load(this + " #content .work");

$('.selected_work img').attr("src", "images/arrow_close.gif");

});


function close_other() {

var selected_work = $('.selected_work');

selected_work.children('.pictures').empty();    
$('.selected_work img').attr("src", "images/arrow_open.gif");
selected_work.removeClass("selected_work")
}

});
```

So now I just need to integrate these 2 bits of code to get them working together... so far no I have had no luck doing this - if I add the scroll (animate) function, the load function stops working...

UPDATE 2

Turns out it was something else which was causing the problem - I now have it working!

Comment: Can you not just move the animate call to the return; after close_other - wont that have the same effect?

Comment: @Spirit, if you have found your own answer. Please post an answer yourself beneath and accept it. This will close the question and make it findable for others in the future.

Comment: Sure - I did try to earlier but the system wouldn't let me answer my own question so quickly... I have posted the answer now but system tells me I have to wait 2 days to accept it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how you scroll the link to the top:

```
$('.work a').click(function() {
     $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top}, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This answered question linked below is closely related and good info for all people that like to be able to

- scroll the page to a certain element, div id
- have that element scroll to the the top of the page by clicking an
  anchor from that element
- have that element scroll to the the top of the page by clicking the
  actual div id containing all the anchor links; "click catcher div"

[Scroll element to top of page by clicking anchor inside element or anywhere inside containing div id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351563/jquery-scroll-element-to-top-of-page-by-clicking-anchor-inside-element-or-anyw)

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but a good reference that you may want to use.

http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

The jQuery scrollTo plugin lets you scroll to any anchor `<a>` in your page. If you just place an anchor on top of your window, you can use scrollTo to go there directly with an animation.

Comment: Thanks - I did look at this but I am not sure it is what I am after exactly as I am not trying to scroll to a different anchor...I want the anchor I just clicked to scroll - and I have figured out how to do that now... just having an issue getting both bits of code to work together without one cancelling the other...